# Sitecore 8 Content Editor error

Tags: server, sitecore, sitecore8, content-editor

Hey I'm getting this error below, I have tried the solutions [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/394385) but can seem to fix it. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Any help would be most appreciated!

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Extensions.ItemExtensions.InheritsFromTemplate(Item item, ID templateId, Boolean recursive) +71
   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Client.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.TreeDefinitionDeployment.Process(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args) +68
   (Object , Object[] ) +79
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +364
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.GetWarnings(Boolean hasSections) +270
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArgs args, Control parent) +177
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item item, Item root, Control parent, Boolean showEditor) +230
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor) +366
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +406
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e) +211

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +37
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +66
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +117
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

Comment: What are you doing when this error happens? Just viewing the page on the CD server?

Comment: Ya I open the Content Editor on the server and I get that error. Everything else works fine just the Content Editor.

Comment: Need more information? What version of sitecore? What modules do you have installed? and so on.

Comment: Two things I usually try are restore a clean instance of the core database, and then get the file distributable for the version I am on and chuck that into the root to ensure nothing is missing. :P 80% of time fixes issues like this! If that doesn't resolve it, then you got some debugging to do!

Comment: No modules installed just a pretty fresh install. Its Sitecore.NET 8.0. I'll give that a try Anicho.

Comment: Can you make sure your project is not referencing a different dll than the site you are deploying into? I see this sometimes when your project which is a based off a template you have, has dlls from a update or two behind.

Comment: Hey Anicho yes it did I had just finished about hour ago. yes that solved the issue. Thanks so much.